# How to highlight the above and below cell of an already highlighted cell?

Tags: highlight, conditional-formatting

I need to highlight 3 cells in a row, where the middle one has today's date.

I can highlight the middle one with a Conditional Formatting, but I can't find a way to highlight the cell directly above and directly below this middle one.

Nonetheless, I tried several methods and formulas, but none had the desired effect.

Anyone has any idea ?

Thank you.

P.S : I tried with Conditional Formatting to highlight any today's date (the middle cell) but after that, i have no clue on how to highlight the other two.

I found MANY ways to highlight neighboring cells relative to a cell's value but none for my specific case.

[My table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycx23.png)

Comment: Anyone has any clue ?

Comment: Not a single person may help ?